# C# control / code to display local HTML file with image tags and CSS

Tags: html, css, winforms, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I am developing an application and part of the design is there is a local folder with HTML files and a folder for images that the HTML files use.

The HTML files can have in-line CSS declaration which will also need to be displayed / rendered. The CSS will be VERY basic like font size , color, padding, etc, but nothing advanced like CSS 3.0 or even advance CSS 2.0 features.

The HTML files are not complicated, just text in tags with a few image tags in there with some CSS to style on some tags. There will be NO JavaScript, NO PHP, etc.. and all the files are local and not loaded from the web.

I can't seem to find a control or code online to display this kind of file contents. I have found some code that will display HTML code but it does not render CSS or render images. This control needs to be read only so the user can not edit the view.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and my application uses WPF WinForms in .NET 4.0.

Just to clarify what I want, I want code to render the above HTML files on my form or a control that allows me to render those HTML files. The control needs to be able to support a scroll bar if the HTML file contents don't fit the control. The control also needs to be able to resize if the form is resized.

Thank you, I look forward to seeing some solutions to this problem! I have never done this before and am excited to see what is available and what you have done in the past to solve this problem!

Comment: Is there some reason why the WebBrowser control won't work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the WebBrowser control and call the Navigate method with Uri pointing to your local file path of your HTML files. The browser control can be displayed inside any Wpf container (grid/border/stackpanel etc).

Reference example is [available at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx).

Comment: I always thought that was a winform non WPF control that only worked for rendering websites from URL's not URI. I figured I am not loading a website so it would not work. I guess I should stop assuming things :). I will try it when I get home, and if it works mark you as the correct answer.